# Why is the use of @Autowired favoured over having multiple instances of application context and calling context.getBean()?

Tags: java, spring, autowired

My understanding is that having multiple instances of the application context is bad practice - there should only be one instance that is passed around, and that instance should be used to call getBean().

However, having a web service make multiple getBean() calls inside every single request that comes in is bad practice for obvious reasons.

Is there any overhead to using @Autowired over getBean()? The only overhead would be during application start up right?

Comment: This seems to be an XY problem. What issue are you actually trying to solve? Injection is about Inversion of Control; calling `getBean` produces coupling - the opposite of IoC. This is why it should not be done.

Comment: Further "_having a web service make multiple getBean() calls inside every single request that comes in is bad practice for obvious reasons_". I don't follow - what are the "_obvious reasons_"? Having **session** scoped or **request** scoped beans proxy autowired into controllers is **exactly** how Spring is designed to work...

Comment: @BoristheSpider, can you please elaborate why do you consider the usage of `getBean()` as coupling ?

Comment: @ShmulikKlein first and foremost you couple to Spring; which is not the only DI framework. But then using `@Autowired` is bad for the same reason - prefer `@Inject` and friends. Secondly, if you use [`getBean(Class)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory.html#getBean-java.lang.Class-) passing an `interface` then you gain nothing - if you specify a specific type then there is obviously coupling. If you use `getBean` with the name, then you couple to bean names; which isn't ideal.

Comment: @ShmulikKlein in short, there is no way to use `getBean` that isn't either 1) exactly the same as injection or 2) subverting IoC.

Comment: I agree, although that I wouldn't use the term 'coupling' for it - 'binds to the framework' or 'binds to the bean's name' seems more accurate to me. No doubt that `@Inject` should be preferred.